# NSXMLParserDelegate Error when upgrading iphone code 3.x code to 4.0

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

I have updated my iphone sdk code from 3.x to 4.0.

I am getting cannot find protocol declaration for NSXMLParserDelegate 
Its showing error when build and debug but when i run application its showing as warning. 
I just want to remove all before submitting to app store

If i added protocol declaration then its not compiling for 3.x

How to overcome this?. I have seen couple of posts but didn't find answer to exact problem.

So i am posting new question here.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have written following code in header files where ever necessary.

I still doubt whether its right approach....

## if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 40000

```
    @interface CustomViewController : UIViewController <..., NSXMLParserDelegate >{
```

## else

```
@interface CustomViewController : UIViewController <....>{
```

## endif